# Java platform takes too much resources

Tags: java, resources

I'm running Win8 on my Intel E2180 2 GHz dual core CPU w/2GByte memory machine.

The point that annoys me most is the line in the Task Manager saying Java(TM) Platform SE binary
It takes from 70% to 85% of the CPU.

My PC just stacks!

Thank you for any advise

Comment: What Java applications do you have running?

Comment: at the moment i run incredimail, chrome and skype.
usually - word/excel and adobe pdf. nothing special

Comment: other than maybe incredimail none of those are java applications. what **JAVA** applications are you running (if you killed the java processes in task manager, what programs close?)

Comment: Can't figure out if incredimail is Java, searching google for "incredimail java" returns many posts from the incredimail forum though, so maybe it is. Does the "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" still appear when you close incredimail?

Answer (score 1):

Running Windows 7/8 with "only" 2GB RAM is certainly not the best experience. Once you add a Java app into the mix - which might itself take 1GB - you only have the absolute minimum RAM left for Windows to work with.

That said, Java should not be constantly taking that % of CPU. Especially since none of the applications you have listed should actually be using Java.

You need to find out what is using Java. Do you keep a web page open that is using a Java component? Try restarting your computer without opening a browser and see if Java is still active.

You may be able to see the command line that is triggering Java from the task manager. Please update your question with the details if you find it. Also try killing the Java task from task manager and see what happens - let us know so that we can help further.

Comment: I've killed that Java process and didn't mention any other process was closed.

Comment: I've restarted the pc and ran the TM at once. The Java process takes the most of resources.

Comment: Java should not be running after a reboot so something in one of the startup processes is causing this. Run some malware checks first. Then use MSconfig to start removing startup tasks until you've cleared it.

Comment: I think you have a legitimate question here. However, as the close reason says, the way it is worded is not really right for a QA site. I suggest editing the question to ask something clearer about what causes Java to be running after a reboot. Then flag the question to try and get it reopened. I'll support you.